# Nasting tables in serializer without foreign key

Tags: django, django-models, serialization, filter, django-rest-framework

Hi everyone I getting null I have a following:

**serializer**

```
class MeasurmentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        
        
        class Meta:
          model = Measurements
          fields = ('measurementid','measurement')
    
    
    class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
          lastmeasurementid = MeasurmentsSerializer(db_column='measurementTime')
          
          class Meta:
            model = Devices
            fields = ("devicename", 'deviceid', 'lastmeasurementid')
```

****Models****

class Devices(models.Model):

```
 devicename = models.CharField(db_column='deviceName', unique=True, max_length=128)  
    lastmeasurementid = models.IntegerField(db_column='lastMeasurementId',blank=True, null=True
```

)

```
class Measurements(models.Model):
    measurementid = models.AutoField(db_column='measurementId', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    deviceid = models.ForeignKey(Devices,   models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="measurment_details", db_column='deviceId')  # Field name made lowercase.
    measurement = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, after a long period of searching, I decide to use row SQL
Visit:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/